# What are colors other than clear suitable for avoiding the heat inside a greenhouse?

Tags: greenhouse

I am in Kuwait where it gets very hot in summer (up to 50C).
I plan to build my greenhouse using polyCarbonite. Can I use another color than clear to avoid the heat inside the greenhouse?

Comment: This sounds like using a refrigerator in Antarctica, no?

Answer (score 4):

I'm rather wondering why you need a greenhouse in such a hot region, but regarding shading of greenhouses, you can buy green coloured shading, usually plastic or polycarbonate of some sort, see link for example

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Greenhouse-Shading-5m-x-6m/dp/B001P3SPIU.

Bear in mind, though, that shading also reduces light levels - more information in the link below. Although its aimed at the UK market, the basic principles regarding methods of shading and cooling are the same

https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=732

Comment: I suspect a greenhouse in that environment helps to keep moisture in/prevent drying out. There is also shading paint, in both white and other colors available.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a product called Aluminet here in Phoenix, AZ. It's a shade cloth available in a variety of shade levels. It reflects some light and diffuses the light passing through, so it' different than just regular shade cloth or greenhouse shade paint.

I've used 50% shade when growing cactus and it works quite well, in my opinion. I don't have a greenhouse though.